# How to exclude NULL blocks from XML using LINQ-to-XML?

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

Consider this XML file. Note the first Tutorial has an Author child element, and the second Tutorial does not:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Tutorials>
  <Tutorial>
    <Author>The Tallest</Author>
    <Title>
      WPF Tutorial - Creating A Custom Panel Control
    </Title>
    <Date>2/18/2008</Date>
  </Tutorial>
    <Tutorial>
    <Title>
      2nd WPF Tutorial - Creating A Custom Panel Control
    </Title>
    <Date>2/18/2008</Date>
  </Tutorial>
</Tutorials>
```

How do I use LINQ-to-XML to load the data that is present? The code below blows up when it gets to the Tutorial section that lacks an author. I cannot figure out how to write the where statement to exclude the block that lacks an author, or how to make the code elegantly skip over the missing data. I have tried this:

```
where tutorial.Element("Title") != null
```

But the above has no effect.... Here is the problem code:

```
XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load("C:\\xml\\2.xml");

var tutorials = from tutorial in xmlDoc.Descendants("Tutorial")
                select new
                {
                    Author = tutorial.Element("Author").Value,
                    Title = tutorial.Element("Title").Value,
                    Date = tutorial.Element("Date").Value,
                };

foreach (var tutorial in tutorials)
{
    Console.WriteLine("author: " + tutorial.Author);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [XElement to String conversion operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff986933.aspx) instead of the [Value property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.value.aspx):

```
var tutorials = from tutorial in xmlDoc.Root.Elements("Tutorial")
                select new
                {
                    Author = (string)tutorial.Element("Author"),
                    Title = (string)tutorial.Element("Title"),
                    Date = (DateTime)tutorial.Element("Date"),
                };
```

Comment: ahhhhh, that does seem to be the ticket! Thank you!!  (in everything I read, this approach did not surface)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of referencing the `Value` property of the `XElement` that might be null, you can do an explicit cast to string instead, like this:

```
Author = (string) tutorial.Element("Author")
```

Check out this article for more info:

- [Improving LINQ Code Smell with Explicit and Implicit Conversion Operators](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ImprovingLINQCodeSmellWithExplicitAndImplicitConversionOperators.aspx)